# PHP Loop Table Items How To Handle it

Tags: php, html, image, loops

```
**table = {
{"Picture 1","URL"},
{"Picture 2","URL"}
}**
```

I'm a Lua programmer, I just want to know if this is possible in PHP too..

```
**// Looping from the table
"<img src='"..v[2].."'></img>"**
```

I'm sorry if I couldn't explain what I want much, I want the images table to loop and create  tags with the links..

Can we loop this table? for example table[i] and i is the number of table items?

Comment: Yes, you can loop on a "list" (aka array) and produce output in the loop.

Comment: ...using `foreach(`) or a for loop with `count()`

Comment: Like every programming language, PHP has arrays and loop structures. Yes, you can do what you want. Is that all you need, or is there something else we can help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can loop through arrays several ways. In this case I think the easiest method would be something like this:

```
$pictures = array(
  array('picture1', 'url'),
  array('picture2', 'url')
);

foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
  // index 1 in $picture will be 'url', index 0 will be 'picture1'
  echo '<img src="'.$picture[1].' alt="'.$picture[0].'"/>';
}
```

You can also get the index of the array by formatting the foreach statement like this:

```
foreach ($pictures as $index -> $picture) {
  ...
```

I'd recommend using an associative array for the url and name for the sake of reliability in accessing properties. For example:

```
$pictures = array(
  array('name' => 'picture1', 'url' => 'someurl.com'),
  array('name' => 'picture2', 'url' => 'someotherurl.com')
);

foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
  echo '<img src="'.$picture['url'].' alt="'.$picture['name'].'"/>';
}
```

You can read more about control structures in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Was it because of the two `<<` before `?php` ? After removing one `<` it appears to work well.

Comment: Didn't do the trick really.. I'll add another pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/HrWXgD1q
Thanks for your answers :)